# Opposite of "Honorific"

Tags: modifiers

I'm wondering if there's a word in English for the opposite of an "honorific". For example, you would call the "Sir" in "Sir Mick Jagger" an honorific.

What would you call the modifiers in a phrase with excessive words indicating inferiority. For example:

- One could be an "author", or one could be an "informal subsection co-author". What would you call "informal subsection co-" in this case?
- one could be the "president" or they could be the "vice-president", is there a word for the "vice-" modifier?

Comment: It would be easier for people to answer if you explain "What would you call the modifiers in "informal subsection subtask co-author"?"  Can you give some examples?

Comment: That was the example, hopefully I clarified.

Comment: Though usually used in a meliorative sense, for a cutesy pet name or nickname, it's may be possible to use *diminutive* in a pejorative sense, to meet your needs here. You are *diminishing* or *minimizing* this co-author.

Comment: Wait, _that's_ the example? Can you give another?

Comment: I'd use 'Damning with faint praise' or 'A disparagement.'

Comment: @DanBron, I think "diminutive" is the word I'm looking for. Can it be used as a noun?

Comment: Yes, it can be used as a noun or an adjective.